# KDE Neon 5.17, on wakeup without external monitor, screen stays black

Tags: multi-monitor, suspend, kde-neon

Sometimes when my laptop wakes up, the screen will stay black. It will only turn on again if I connect an external screen. After that the screen works again. Then I can disconnect the external screen and the main screen will work fine.
When I investigate the `~/.local/share/kscreen/outputs/` folder,
it looks like the output goes through `DP-1`. But it should be going through `eDP-1` (main laptop screen)

When I have only the main laptop screen connected and the screen works, `xrandr` gives me the following output:

```
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
```

System logs did not gave me any more clues.

System info:

[image]

Anybody has a fix for this?

Comment: I have noticed that if the screen stays black at wake up, when i go into tty2 mode (Ctrl+Alt+F2) and back (Ctrl+Alt+F1) the screen works again.